# Windows Server 2012 R2 - System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-server-2012-r2, system.io.file

I have an application developed in C# which runs fine on my Windows 7 x64 PC but when I try to run the same application on my Windows Server 2012 R2 VPS, I get an error that "(TheApplicationName" Has stopped working)

When I click on the view problem details, I get the following information

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: application.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 582aa3a2
  Problem Signature 04: Application
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 582aa3a2
  Problem Signature 07: 1
  Problem Signature 08: 77
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 6ee2
  Additional Information 4: 6ee2432e64e99bdcea5e4be767a3b1a2

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Could anyone kindly advise what the problem is here

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, mislaid my crystal ball. Could you please post some of your code, specifically where file access fails?

Comment: Add a `Try...Catch` around your Main function and log the exception message,  in error case, to the Event Log

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your application references a binary (.dll) not found on target machine. Please go through all (non-System) referenced binaries in your project and make sure they reside within the same folder as your application.